# Script adding launchers to the top gnome panel

Tags: 12.04, scripts, gnome-panel

For a large number of machines running 12.04 with gnome-classic. I'd like to script adding launchers to the top left of the gnome panel.

I know how to add them manually but this is a tedious procedure.

Does anyone know if it is possible to script this?

Comment: " I know how to add them manually " example of these actions? and in general I would throw these actions in a script and execute the script.

Comment: I can add them by dragging a Menu icon from the Menu to the gnome panel. But I think it is not possible via command line to add a launcher but maybe via editing .desktop file or similar? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1238559

Comment: try this link [Create a Panel Launcher from Bash/Terminal...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483781) and this [How do I add a launcher to a panel during rpm install in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329075/how-do-i-add-a-launcher-to-a-panel-during-rpm-install-in-red-hat-enterprise-linu).

Answer (score 1):

- Just to make script easier, made assumption:

  1. default top panel is `'top-panel-0'` got from:

     ```
     gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list
     ```
  2. Not many icons already up there in the panel, just to avoid overwriting other object with same index (ex: `'object-0-9'`), got from:

     ```
     gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list
     ```

  Objective script:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.object:/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-0-9/ object-iid 'PanelInternalFactory::Launcher'    
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.object:/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-0-9/ toplevel-id 'top-panel-0'    
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.object:/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-0-9/ pack-type 'start'
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.object:/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-0-9/ pack-index 1
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.launcher:/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-0-9/instance-config/ location '/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop'
  gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list "[`gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list  | awk '{ gsub("\[|\]",""); print;}'`, 'object-0-9']"
  ```
- To reset/remove all launchers, I couldn't get `gsettings reset` to work with data stored without schema (API may be not supporting that), whereas `dconf reset` does:

  ```
  for o in $(dconf list /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/); do if [ ! "${o##object*}" ] ; then dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/$o; fi; done
  dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/object-id-list "`dconf read /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/object-id-list | awk '{ gsub(/(, [:\47]object-[0-9]-[0-9][:\47]|[:\47]object-[0-9]-[0-9][:\47], )*/,"");  print; }'`"
  ```

**Notes:**

- Better to use `dconf-editor` to see or make quick key changes for testing.
- Use monitor dconf changes &  what the script is doing:

  ```
  dconf watch /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
  ```

Comment: I tried your objective script and it worked. But I do get some very strange behavior now. When I reboot, half of my launchers are gone. And when I drag a launcher to the desktop it says:
Error while copying
There was an error getting information about "terminator-amigos.desktop".
Error when getting information for file '/home/maxbaeten/Desktop/terminator-amigos.desktop': No such file or directory.
Is there a way to cleanly remove all launchers?

Comment: @MaxBaeten, updated answer, BTW better to `dconf-editor` get clear view of store data. (keep in mind, its path tree is not updated till closed & reloaded again)